# Leaflet circle radius unit?

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet circle has two radius properties: `_mRadius`, which is the radius in meter, and `_radius`. Is `_radius` in radians or what is the unit of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_radius` can't be in radians, because radians are not units of lengths. It is, in fact, in pixels. This is how it is [initialized](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/stable/src/layer/vector/Circle.js):

```
this._point = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlng);
this._radius = Math.max(this._point.x - pointLeft.x, 1);
```

The property is used for SVG / Canvas output in `getPathString()` function.

Comment: radius: Number; Radius of the circle, in meters.